# Want to register hosted background service through Autofac in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

I have tried to register a background service through Autofac, but my code is not able to resolve the dependency. If anyone did the same thing, please paste the answer here.

I try to register the Hosted service in `program.cs` and try to register to resolve dependency through Autofac.

```
builder.RegisterType<DailyUpdateWorkitemStatusSchedularTask>()
       .As<IHostedService>()
       .AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Program.cs

```
services.AddHostedService<DailyUpdateWorkitemStatusSchedularTask>();
```

Method #2: try to resolve using Populate method in Autofac.

Note: not able to register.

Comment: According to autofac, official document ASP.NET Core requires you to specify a service provider factory directly rather than adding it to the service collection. In addition, it requires [`Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/) in order to resolve the dependency issues. Please [`have a look at this official document`](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/netcore.html) for details

Comment: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection already installed

Comment: Have you tried the steps described in the document I have shared? What challenges you are getting at this moment could you please share in details?

Comment: DailyUpdateWorkitemStatusSchedularTask having a dependency of another service as well .
private readonly ManageWorkstreamStatus _manageWorkstreamStatus;
        public DailyUpdateWorkitemStatusSchedularTask(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory, ManageWorkstreamStatus manageWorkstreamStatus) : base(serviceScopeFactory)
        {
            _manageWorkstreamStatus = manageWorkstreamStatus;
        }

Comment: From your given error  description and shared code snippet its hard to reproduce your issue, it would be great if you can share more details or provide [minium reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)